# Javascript click function only work once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu with a submit function that executes, if any children from the dropdown is clicked.
Now I want to prevent the submit function to a special li element, because there should be insert a tracking id in a popup iFrame.

With the following code it works so far on the first dropdown menu and prevent the submit function, but it wont work on all following dropdown's.

Maybe someone has a short solution for me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.track').click(function(){
        stopPropagation();
});

$('.dropdown li').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('opt').value = $(this).data('value');
        $('#options').submit();
});        

$("#options").submit(function() {
    if (confirm('are you sure?')){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
});
</script>
<form name="" action="" method="post" id="options">
    <input type="hidden" name="update" id="opt" value="">
    <div id="item-select-option">
    <div class="dropdown"> 
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Options&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul id="selector" class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                <li data-value="paid"><a href="#">paid</a></li>
                <li data-value="shipped"><a href="#">shipped</a></li>
                <li class="track"><a href="tracking.php" class="trackbox" data-fancybox-type="iframe">track</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I would imagine your JS crashes after the first click, because ``event`` is not defined.

Comment: after edit the id to class, the form submitted every time and the trackbox class isn't called i think(iFrame in new Window now).

Comment: Now it works, i deleted the event from the     
$('.track').click(function(event)
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:** You've several elements with the id `track/options` when the `id`  attribute should be unique in same document, so when you attach event to the `id` just the first element with this id that will be attached.

**Suggested solution :**

Use class instead of `id`'s, like :

```
<form name="" action="" method="post" class="options">
    .....
    <li class="track">
        <a href="tracking.php" class="trackbox" data-fancybox-type="iframe">track</a>
    </li>
</form>
```

Then you js should be like :

```
$('.track').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".options").submit(function() {
    if (confirm('are you sure?')){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** The `event` should be present in anonymous function `function(event)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Same problem as OP's code: ``event`` is not defined.

Comment: Missed that, thanks for you intervention... updated my answer

Comment: I can only see one `track` in OP's code. Where did you see multiple.

Comment: Maybe you need to read the OP? I only see one `track` as well

Comment: Thank you Zakaria,
i edit it to class but now the form submit in every dropdown.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm i mean read the full OP not just the code please. you could see _but it wont work on all following dropdown's_

Comment: but now my function dont call and it submitted every time.

Comment: Works fine now?

Comment: @tobiass what's the problem ? what removing the correct answer marks?